# Align Text Beside FontAwesome Icon

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

Hi I'm having trouble trying to align text beside a font awesome icon I've tried a few things but non of them seem to be working what i'm trying to do is make a panel with a button on one side that you can click and it calls the number with the fontawesome icon and text on the other side of the panel (I'm using bootstrap v3.3.2 to build it)

Here an image I've  what I'm trying to do
[image]

and here an image of what it currently looks like
[image]

```html
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-body">
    <div class="col-lg-8">
      <i class="fa fa-phone fa-2x" style="align: middle;"></i>
      <h3>Call us</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 text-center">
      <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified" style="align: middle;" role="group" aria-label="...">
        <div class="btn-group" role="group">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" <a href="tel:">Click the button to call us</a>
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Include the entire CSS I see you are using bootstrap .... `h3` is block element are you changing that? how?

Comment: @DanielPinzon There's no custom styling for the h3 element just bootstraps own styling

Comment: Try to replicate your issue I can't https://jsfiddle.net/n336Lnwf/

Comment: @DanielPinzon https://jsfiddle.net/pw58uf4w/ here the code with my css

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To have complete/independent control on the position of the font-awesome icon, try something like below.

**Method 1:** Using `absolute positioning`

1. Add `position with` a `property value` of `relative` to the `h3` style to control overlap.
2. Use `:after` selector `content` to insert the icon
3. Add `position with` a `property value` of `absolute` to the `h3` :after block of CSS code
4. Achieve the desired position with left, right, top or bottom property values.

**Method 2:** Using `float`(Easier).

1. Use `:after` selector `content` value to insert the icon
2. Achieve the desired position of the icon by floating the `:before` selector to the right or left.

```css
/* Using absolute positoinning */

h3.absolute {
  position: relative; /* Helps us control overlap */
  padding-left: 25px; /* Creates space for the Phone Icon */
  }

 h3.absolute:before {
  content: '\f095';
  font-family: fontAwesome;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0; /* Adjust as needed */
  top: 3px; /* Adjust as needed */
  }
  
 /* Using float */

  h3.float {
  font-size: 24px;
  color: red;
  }

 h3.float:before {
  content: '\f095';
  font-family: fontAwesome;
  float: left; /* Depends on the side we want the icon */
  margin-right: 10px; /* Creates space between the icon and the text */
  font-size: 24px;
  height: 32px;
  line-height: 32px; /* Same as the font size */
  }
  
  
  /* Below code is jsut for differentiation of methods */
  strong {
  font-size: 24px;
  text-decoration: underline;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  }
  
  strong:last-of-type {
  color: red;
  }
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<strong>Using absolute Positioning</strong>
<h3 class="absolute">Call us</h3>

<strong>Using float</strong>
<h3 class="float">Call us</h3>
```

**Note:** You can adjust the size of the icon with CSS `font-size` property value.

Answer (score 11):

There is a very easy way if your fontawesome has the same font-size than your text (it is usually the good practice), include the  tags in the text tags:

```
<p>
  <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
 Text text text
</p>
```

Answer (score 6):

Try this :

```
<i class="fa fa-phone fa-2x" style="vertical-align: middle;"></i>
```

Comment: Yup.  It's probably a `vertical-align` issue.  That or it's floated and needs the float removed and `display:inline` or `display:inline-block` added along with the vertical align.  Don't use inline styles though.  That's bad.  Demo of the solution: http://jsfiddle.net/gcp3qbu4/

Answer (score 2):

Use the .media class.

```
<div class="media">
    <div class="media-left">
        <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="media-body">
        Cras sit amet nibh libero, in gravida nulla. Nulla vel metus scelerisque ante sollicitudin commodo. Cras purus odio, vestibulum in vulputate at, tempus viverra turpis. Fusce condimentum nunc ac nisi vulputate fringilla. Donec lacinia congue felis in faucibus.
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried this but am not too keen on it because it seems to have been designed to always take maximum width of its parent container because it was designed for things like picture beside comments. Although you can obviously set a width, this is not so easy when you're dealing with multiple languages. However, I will up-vote because it was something I was completely unaware of and a good-to-know feature of Bootstrap.

Answer (score 1):

For posterity, if you are willing to go with CSS flexbox, aligning icons besides text is trivial.

I've kept Bootstrap and its Panel as part of the solution in the spirit of answering the original question.

The key points to note here are:

- `display: flex` to make direct children flow in the default direction (row)
- `align-items: center` to align along the flex direction (vertical align in this case)
- `flex: 1` to get the middle section to expand as much as possible, pushing the two sides apart

```css
.banner {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.banner-start h3 {
  display: inline-block;
}

.banner-start i {
  padding: 0 6px;
}

.banner-middle {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-body">
    <div class="banner">
      <div class="banner-start">
        <i class="fa fa-phone fa-2x"></i>
        <h3>Call us</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="banner-middle">

      </div>
      <div class="banner-end">
        <div class="btn-group" role="group">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"><a href="tel:">Click the button to call us</a>
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you might need to add position to item. If both elements are on the same column or div and Picture/Icon is larger than something like this should work.

> .position-fix {  position: sticky;  top: 50%; }