# Bootstrap Display Multiple Controls Inline

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, razor

I have this extract from my Razor display layout:

```
...more controls here
    <div class="control-group">
     @Html.LabelFor(model => model.BankAccountType, new { @class = "control-label" })
      <div class="controls">
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.BankAccountType)
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.AccountTypeValid)
      </div>
    </div>
...more controls here
```

This is the display template I have for AccountTypeValid:

```
@model string
@if (Model == "Y")
{
    <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
}
else if (Model == "U")
{
    <i class="fa fa-question"></i>
}
```

It renders like this:

[image: fa images appear on a new line]

How do I get the fa images to appear in-line with the text value?

Comment: Just add `pull-left` on icon `<i class="fa fa-check pull-left"></i>`

Comment: Tried both pull-left and pull-right, but in both cases the image is still on a new line below the text value.

Comment: can you share generated html & css so we can identify the issue

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28587943/align-text-beside-fontawesome-icon