# How to add e-mail and address to a pre-installed wordpress theme using CSS

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I want to add e-mail and telephone number next to logo using `css`. I want to show also icons for these.

Now I'm using a plugin but I'm not satisfied.

My site is [www.medifastservices.com](https://www.medifastservices.com)

My current code is:

```
<div class="container">
                <div class="site-branding">
                <div class="site-brand-inner has-logo-img"><div class="site-logo-div"><a href="https://www.medifastservices.com/" class="custom-logo-link  no-t-logo" rel="home" itemprop="url"><img width="170" height="53" src="https://www.medifastservices.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/ico-ambulance-e1533995942143.png" class="custom-logo" alt="MediFast Services" itemprop="logo" /></a></div></div>                </div>
                <div class="header-right-wrapper">
                    <a href="#0" id="nav-toggle">Menu<span></span></a>
                    <nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation" role="navigation">
                        <ul class="onepress-menu">
                            <li id="menu-item-41" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-home current-menu-item page_item page-item-11 current_page_item menu-item-41"><a href="https://www.medifastservices.com/">Homepage</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-42" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-42"><a href="https://www.medifastservices.com/ambulance/">Ambulance</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-43" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-43"><a href="https://www.medifastservices.com/courier/">Courier</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-86" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-86"><a href="tel:+35722100444">22100444</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                    <!-- #site-navigation -->
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use fontawesome to use email and Phone icons

Comment: Yes sure, but I want to add the text firstly.

Answer (score 0):

Hi there you can do something like using :after selector.
Hope this link will be helpful to you [Align Text Beside FontAwesome Icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28587943/align-text-beside-fontawesome-icon)

If you want to add the text first you can use :before selector in css to the tag in which you have your icon.